# Why rescue an exception and then raise one?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, exception

I'm looking at the mandrill docs for a ruby api call https://mandrillapp.com/api/docs/users.ruby.html#method=ping and I noticed that they rescue `Mandrill::Error` and then `raise` another exception.

I'm curious why anyone would ever catch one exception and then raise another one. It doesn't make sense to me.

```
begin
    mandrill = Mandrill::API.new 'YOUR_API_KEY'
    result = mandrill.users.ping 
        # {"PING"=>"PONG!"}

rescue Mandrill::Error => e
    # Mandrill errors are thrown as exceptions
    puts "A mandrill error occurred: #{e.class} - #{e.message}"
    # A mandrill error occurred: Mandrill::InvalidKeyError - Invalid API key    
    raise
end
```

Comment: to add additional info for debugging?

Comment: Doesn't make sense in this case: all information logged is in the exception. Note that the **same** exception is re-thrown, not a new exception.

Comment: Rethrowing could be useful in general in case you need to free resources prior to throwing your hands up and saying "I don't know how to handle this problem".  In this case,  though,  simply displaying an error with info someone could have inferred from the impending stack trace seems sort of useless.

Answer (score 8):

```
rescue Mandrill::Error => e
    # Mandrill errors are thrown as exceptions
    puts "A mandrill error occurred: #{e.class} - #{e.message}"
    # A mandrill error occurred: Mandrill::InvalidKeyError - Invalid API key    
    raise
end
```

In this case the same exception is being "re-raised". The only reason for this `rescue` block is to log specific information about the exception.

`begin/rescue` blocks are usually used this way when an exception is of special interest and so the authors wanted the exception info to be printed/logged. This is especially the case when the next `rescue` block is not printing any exception information and instead silently handling it.

Answer (score 0):

`raise` will throws a runtime exception instead of a normal exception.

Another reason for doing it could be that code wanted to throw a runtime error instead of a normal error. Maybe relevant if the code is in the context of a controller.

However, I think the main reason will be Martin's logging answer.

Comment: `raise` will throw the last exception. IOW: it throws the *exact same* exception that was just caught. Your explanation doesn't make sense.